# logcat displays launch but activity doesnt launch in emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Friends, I am really struck up in a really really weird problem.

My logcat shows the activity is launched but the emulator simply shows a blank white page instead of the desired activity(In logcat, `Clfbpg` is the java file which wont load).

Here is the logcat.

```
02-23 16:00:43.237: I/ActivityManager(65): Displayed activity com.tmrepo/.Client: 4387 ms (total 4387 ms)  
02-23 16:00:45.287: D/dalvikvm(293): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46 objects / 2168 bytes in 9619ms  
02-23 16:00:55.946: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2219 objects / 86480 bytes in 320ms  
02-23 16:00:56.236: W/KeyCharacterMap(263): No keyboard for id 0  
02-23 16:00:56.236: W/KeyCharacterMap(263): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin  
02-23 16:00:58.656: D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 766 objects / 42248 bytes in 7048ms  
02-23 16:01:04.418: I/ActivityManager(65): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.tmrepo/.Clwelcome2 }  
02-23 16:01:06.887: I/ActivityManager(65): Displayed activity com.tmrepo/.Clwelcome2: 2112 ms (total 2112 ms)  
02-23 16:01:10.520: D/dalvikvm(702): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6993 objects / 306016 bytes in 236ms  
02-23 16:01:15.327: I/ActivityManager(65): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.tmrepo/.Clfbpg }  
02-23 16:01:17.237: I/ActivityManager(65): Displayed activity com.tmrepo/.Clfbpg: 1777 ms (total 1777 ms)`
```

My app has many pages where just one particular page is not loading. other pages work fine.
I did every possible thing to get that page running but just cant get the error.

I tried connecting another layout to the java file instead of the layout I wanted. But all is same.

My XML Code is
`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/feedback"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texthome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff0057" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tbproname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/proname"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbproname"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/feedback" />
```

`

I think the problem is with java file.

And my java file is
` package com.tmrepo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Clfbpg extends Activity {

```
EditText tbproname;
TextView texthome;
Button submit;


public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feedform);


    tbproname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbproname);
    texthome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texthome);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    //scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    texthome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent1();
            finish();
        }

        public void Intent1() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i1 = new Intent();
            i1.setClass(Clfbpg.this,Clwelcome2.class);
            startActivity(i1);          }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent2();
            finish();
        }

        public void Intent2() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i2 = new Intent();
            i2.setClass(Clfbpg.this,Clwelcome2.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    }); 
}}
```

Can anyone here has any idea about this irritating problem?
Many Thanks. I have been trying to solve it since 2 days.

Comment: Does your oncreate method gets executed???

Comment: @shachi please check my below update and let me know

Comment: you should @Override the onCreate !!!!!

Comment: In logcat it shows executed... but not in emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember about androidmainfest.xml and just think . Make sure that yo are first adding to Clfbpg class activity first. check in AndroidManifest.xml  file.

```
<activity android:name="Clfbpg"> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</activity>
```

this should be call first . tell me about it.

Comment: but, I dont want it as first activity... It has intents and all other pages except this are working

Comment: first check that your this Clfbpg  is working . avoid all other class for Now. and just call Clfbpg by my above code and see this is working or not . inform me about

Comment: well...many thanks for help...but I really had very less time to finish it so I just deleted that particular class and xml file. And made a new one. So,after that its working. Still,thanks for the effort ..

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add these two line in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="Clfbpg">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />          <-----
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  <----
...
</activity>
```

So, It will create icon on mobile screen and you will be able to launch your app.

Comment: the app is launching perfectly... from 1st page to last page...except this one activity.... And I dont wont this activity to launch first...So,how can i put MAIN???