# "No Launcher Activity found!" while launching a service on startup

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I wrote a simple Service which should be invoked on startup.
I don't haver (or need) any activities to be invoked on startup, but only that service.
Here is my manifest - what am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicelistening"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <receiver android:name=".Index" >
              <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                    <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" /> 
              </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

         <receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">
               <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
               </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".OnOffService" android:enabled="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: there is no activity main launch, so you need to add activity to first launch

Comment: See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15039765/1289716)

Comment: These solutions suggest using Activities, but as said I don't need those. Is there an option for launching my Service without launching any Activity?

Answer (score 0):

The “No Launcher Activity found!” message is not something that should throw you off, since you already know that no launcher activity is found. You can simply ignore this error. To launch your service, broadcast the intent that is needed, and your code will run. If you want, you can add a simple test activity that will test this - but really,

**no further action is required.**